# z-compound-depth on links not working after a group is collapsed

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have multiple nested groups(compound node) in my graph and trying to add a new group with z-index-compare:"manual" and z-compound-depth:"top" for all the links and nodes in that group so that this group remains on the top always. It is working just fine. But now when I collapse any other group then the links which have z-compound-depth:"top" are rendered behind. Looks like it is not honored.
Could you please take a look at and provide any solution?
I have created a simple fiddle to reproduce this issue.

`Demo`https://jsfiddle.net/kmprakashbabu/tug2e01r/8/

Reproduction Steps:

1. Run the fiddle. You will see a group "p1"
2. Now click "Add Top Group" button from left. A new group "p2" will be added and drag around to see that it remains always on top of the group "p1"
3. Now collapse "p1" and see that all the links in "p2" and the links connecting "p1" and "P2" will go behind the "p2".

Thanks
Prakash

Comment: your aim is not clear. After collapsing a compound, you cannot see what is inside. So you can not also see the edges inside. What is the problem?

Comment: @canbx Thank you for your reply. I understand if I collapse a compound then all the elements are hidden. My requirement is that if I collapse "p1" it should not affect "p2". Even though I set the z-compound-depth for the the nodes and edges for "p2", the edges are drawn behind the "p2" when "p1" is collapsed. I expect them to be drawn on top and be interactable. Since they are drawn behind I am not able to interact with the links. I added transparency to demonstrate that the links are drawn behind the group "p2". Also would like add another point, "p2" has no parent.